# C# datagridview MySql adapter update does not work

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have problem in my winforms app when I try to save changes inside `datagridview`. Am using `MySql` but updating and deleting does not work with adapter update. I read many tutorials and examples from here and codeproject but cant understand where I make mistake?

When I make changes inside col item and press on button `save` and call `click` event I get message box `Updated`. When I refresh and check in database record does not updated.

Pleas check my code if you have time:

```
public partial class GroupsForm : Form
{
    private MySqlConnection conn;
    private MySqlDataAdapter adapter;
    private MySqlCommand cmd;
    private DataTable table;
    private MySqlCommandBuilder sqlCommandBuilder = null;
    private BindingSource bs;
    private DataSet ds;
    private String query;
    private int rowIndex = 0;

    private void GrupsForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String connectionString = Properties.Settings.Default.connectionString;
        conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
        query = "SELECT * FROM groups";

        conn.Open();

        adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, conn);
        ds = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(ds, "groups");
        grupeDataGridView.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
    }

    private void saveUpdateBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            MySqlCommandBuilder cmb = new MySqlCommandBuilder(adapter);
            adapter.Update(ds, "groups");
            grupeDataGridView.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

            MessageBox.Show("Updated");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Update failed");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What you are trying to do can be done with a bit less code, but it looks like it should work.  Are looking in the database to see if the changes are applied?  The `Fill` and `Update` methods return an `int` indicating how many rows were affected - your code will show the messagebox  as long as there is no exception - you might want to examine the `rowsAffected` return value

Comment: Like i say i check in database and data is not saved. Does i need extra update sql statement or adapter update is enothgt

Comment: `int rowsAffected = adapter.Update(...)` what does that return?  As I said, your messagebox will show almost always

Comment: Now i debug `int rowsAffected  = adapter.Update(ds, "grupe");` return `0`

Comment: `"grupe"` != `"groups"`  was that a typo?

Comment: sorry for that i translate becouse is on another language. I forgot to translate `grupe` to `groups`

Comment: If you made changes to one of the rows, the only reason I can think of that it would not update `n` rows is if you have some code in an event doing something to stop it.  Is there maybe some data validation code somewhere?

Comment: no, validation code does not exist. That is full code

Comment: When updating, you should first call `yourDataGridView.EndEdit()`.

Comment: Nothing again is the some

Comment: Sorry, cannot reproduce.

Comment: I checked everything in a clean example and it worked properly.

Comment: Hmmm changes is saved in `MySql` database? Realy? What than can be problem?

Comment: My connection string is inside settings `server=localhost;user id=root;database=trgomanager; pooling = false; convert zero datetime=True`. With that string am successfull doing create and select statements

Comment: If the connection string was wrong you wouldn't get any data in the SELECT.  Try a simple test on a new, clean project.  I'll bet somewhere you have something discarding changes